# TSQL Average time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a simple Stored Procedure that I am using to show some basic user stats. I am displaying the total number of submissions, the total time spend across all of those submissions as well as the average time spent.

I am running into two issues with this. First, this breaks when there is more than one records in the inner selects.

The second question I have is how to properly calculate the average time of all records for that user.

Could some one point out some ways I can change the below code in order to get the total time and average time across all records, not just one?

```
SELECT count(itemID) AS totalSubmissions,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETUTCDATE(), 100) as lastUpdate,
       (
        SELECT COALESCE(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, s.startTime, s.endTime + 1) , 0)
        FROM itemTracker_records as s
        WHERE QID = @QID
       ) as totalTime,
       (
        SELECT COALESCE(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, s.startTime, s.endTime + 1) , 0)
        FROM itemTracker_records as s
        WHERE QID = @QID
       ) as averageTime 
FROM   itemTracker_records
WHERE  QID = @QID
FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
```

Comment: [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)? Divide by [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Of course it will break - there is no aggregation in the subqueries. Though, in this particular case, it doesn't look that you ever need them.
2. Average is calculated, surprisingly enough, by the `AVG()` function.
3. (Educated guess) you probably meant that you need at least one minute time, if start and end are specified but equal? Alas, in your code you add 1 day - fixed.

So the result will look similar to this:

```
SELECT count(r.itemID) AS totalSubmissions,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETUTCDATE(), 100) as lastUpdate,
    sum(isnull(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, r.startTime, r.endTime) + 1 , 0)) as [totalTime],
    avg(isnull(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, r.startTime, r.endTime) + 1 , 0)) as [averageTime]
FROM   dbo.itemTracker_records r
WHERE  r.QID = @QID
FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Last, but not least: never forget schemas and object aliases unless you are intentionally trying to confuse someone, yourself included.